# .NET Core 2.2 web app only works after establishing connection to API endpoint

Tags: ios, .net, angular

I've built a web application using Angular 7.3.8 and .NET Core 2.2. During testing of this web application, the app launches and displays data in all android devices. However, the app will load up on ios devices but the data is not being displayed.

We figured this was an issue with authentication of some sort, so on the ios device we directly connected to the API and got a response back. After getting the response back, when we refresh the original web app, the data is now being displayed. Has anyone experienced this or have an idea of why I'm not getting any data back until we manually establish that connection with the API? Any insights would be appreciated.

Angular Service:

```
getUserInfo(): Observable<UserInfo> {
    var url = this.baseUrl + 'user';
    return this.http.get<UserInfo>(url, { withCredentials: true });
  }
```

ASP.NET Core Web API:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly LibertyAccessContext _context;
    private ILogger<UserController> _logger { get; }

    public UserController(LibertyAccessContext context, ILogger<UserController> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }


    // GET: api/User
    [HttpGet]
    public UserSettings Get()
    {
        try
        {
            if (User.Identity.Name == null)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }

            var userSettings = _context.UserSettings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.LanId == User.Identity.Name);
            if (userSettings != null)
            {
                return userSettings;
            }
```

Comment: You need to share your code so we can help you

Comment: @TonyNgo I've updated the main post with some code, thanks.